# GraphQL-dotnet fields Validation Prior Resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I'm building GraphQL API in Asp.Net Core 2.2 using GraphQL.Net 2.4.0

I've created Controller to handle GraphQL Queries:

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class GraphQLController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISchema _schema;
    private readonly IDocumentExecuter _executer;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    IEnumerable<IValidationRule> _validationRules;
    private readonly DataLoaderDocumentListener _dataLoaderDocumentListener;

    //private readonly IDocumentWriter _writer;
    //private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public GraphQLController(
        ILogger<GraphQLController> logger,
        IEnumerable<IValidationRule> validationRules,
        IDocumentExecuter executer,
        DataLoaderDocumentListener dataLoaderDocumentListener,
        //IDocumentWriter writer,
        ISchema schema)
    {
        _executer = executer;
        _schema = schema;
        _logger = logger;
        _validationRules = validationRules;
        _dataLoaderDocumentListener = dataLoaderDocumentListener;
        //_writer = writer;
    }

    [Route("graphql")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody]GraphQLQuery query)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid || query == null)
        {
            return Json("Проблем в формата на изпратената на заявка!");
        }            

        var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();

        var result = await _executer.ExecuteAsync(o =>
        {
            o.Schema = _schema;
            o.Query = query.Query;
            o.OperationName = query.OperationName;
            o.Inputs = inputs;
            o.ExposeExceptions = true;
            o.EnableMetrics = true;

            o.ComplexityConfiguration = new GraphQL.Validation.Complexity.ComplexityConfiguration { MaxDepth = 15 };
            //o.FieldMiddleware.Use<InstrumentFieldsMiddleware>();
            o.UserContext = new GraphQLUserContext
            {
                // this is the User on your controller
                // which is populated from your jwt
                User = User

            };
            o.ValidationRules = DocumentValidator.CoreRules().Concat(_validationRules).ToList();
            o.Listeners.Add(_dataLoaderDocumentListener);

        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (result.Errors?.Count > 0)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"Errors: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Errors)}");
            return BadRequest(result);
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

The problem arises when i want to validate some of the Fields in my `InputObjectGraphType` , I've implemented `IValidationRule` interface.

Prior this im adding Metadata to the field i want to validate so i can easily find it. I;m getting the fieldType but cant fetch the Value to Validate it.

This is the Implementation of the `IValidationRule` i Use:

```
    public class PhoneNumberValidationRule : IValidationRule
{
    public INodeVisitor Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {
        return new EnterLeaveListener(_ =>
        {
            _.Match<Argument>(argAst =>
            {
                var inputType = context.TypeInfo.GetInputType().GetNamedType() as InputObjectGraphType;
                var argDef = context.TypeInfo.GetArgument();
                if (argDef == null) return;

                var type = argDef.ResolvedType;
                if (type.IsInputType())
                {
                    var fields = ((type as NonNullGraphType)?.ResolvedType as IComplexGraphType)?.Fields;

                    if (fields != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var field in fields)
                        {
                            if (field.ResolvedType is NonNullGraphType)
                            {
                                if ((field.ResolvedType as NonNullGraphType).ResolvedType is IComplexGraphType)
                                {
                                    fields = fields.Union(((field.ResolvedType as NonNullGraphType).ResolvedType as IComplexGraphType)?.Fields);
                                }
                            }
                            if (field.ResolvedType is IComplexGraphType)
                            {
                                fields = fields.Union((field.ResolvedType as IComplexGraphType)?.Fields);
                            }
                        }

                        //let's look for fields that have a specific metadata
                        foreach (var fieldType in fields.Where(f => f.HasMetadata(nameof(EmailAddressValidationRule))))
                        {
                            //now it's time to get the value
                            context.Inputs.GetValue(argAst.Name, fieldType.Name);
                            if (value != null)
                            {
                                if (!value.IsValidPhoneNumber())
                                {
                                    context.ReportError(new ValidationError(context.OriginalQuery
                                    , "Invalid Phone Number"
                                    , "The supplied phone number is not valid."
                                    , argAst
                                    ));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But here the context.Inputs property is always null. 
In the controller this line `var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();`
also produces null. Is this query Variable field and Document Executer's Input Field anything to do with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured it out by now, but for anyone finding this question in the future:
context.Inputs is only used with variables.
As far as I could understand argAst.GetValue could be either VariableReference or ObjectValue depending on whether the query was using a variable or not.
In case variables were not used context.Inputs.GetValue will return null.